# How can we write this inequality as an LMI?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be positive definite matrices. How can we write the following inequality as an LMI?

$$XY - Z^2 - I \succ 0$$

Here, $I$ is the identity matrix.

For example, if it was $XY-Z^2Y-I>0$, its corresponding LMI would be readily accessible by:

$$
(X-Z^2)Y-I>0 \ \ \Big(\text{assuming that $X-Z^2>0$}\Big) \to\begin{bmatrix}X-Z^2 &I\\I &Y\end{bmatrix}>0
$$
$$
 \to \begin{bmatrix}X & I & Z\\I & Y & 0\\Z &0&I\end{bmatrix}>0
$$
which is linear in terms of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: What do you mean by "LMI" ? And what is the connection with Schur's complement ?

Comment: LMI means linear matrix inequality

Comment: An answer to my second question dealing with your title ?

Comment: Do you want it to be linear in $X$ and $Y$ too?

Comment: Yes X and Y and Z are sdpvariables which are supposed to appear in a convex optimization

Comment: I just suggest the schur complement you can apply any approach you want to change it into LMI

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear what is fixed and what is the decision variable. If $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are all free sdpvariables (in the YALMIP context, I guess), then $X=Y=2I$ and $Z=I$ is a feasible solution. But I guess you are looking for something different?

Comment: Note also that $XY$ is not necessary a symmetric matrix. Probably you should rewrite it as $XY+YX -2Z^2-2I > 0$.

Comment: Yes you are right XY should be positive definite, and if you change the presented inequality into LMI it would be apparent in your final LMI

Comment: for example if it was, $XY+Z^2Y-I>0$ the corresponding LMI is : $\begin{bmatrix}X &I &Z\\I&Y&0\\Z&0&I\end{bmatrix}>0$

Comment: Sorry I meant if it was $XY-Z^2Y-I>0$

Comment: Which the positive definiteness of $XY$ is apparent from the corresponding LMI

Comment: ofcourse I will do that